# Python maplotlib sine curve with random.randn

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, curve, trigonometry

I am pretty new to Python and have following question:

I generated numpy arrays with the following code:

```
X = np.random.randn(1000)*2
Y = np.sin(x)
```

How can I obtain a visualization of above data which looks similar to:

[image]

Thank you guys for any help!

Comment: If you want to visualize a function (e.g. `sin`), you don't want a random vector as `X`, you want to use `np.linspace` to sample points uniformly across the `X` axis. To visualize them, use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/).

Comment: Actually it is going to look like a sine curve, but since x values are coming from a normal distribution, there will be less points as you move away from the mean of the normal distribution (0). However, it would make more sense to use np.linspace instead of np.random.randn

Comment: Why do you want to use random values for `X`?

Comment: yes, well it has to look like this. And I can only do operations on the generated arrays. To use the index as x values was my first idea too. But after a thousand tries, I thought it's the wrong way. That's what I tried first: indicesX=np.argsort(X). so I have the indices of the random values. then I tried to plot it like this: plt.plot(indicesX,Y).

Comment: well I am not allowed to change the way my arrays are generated. I can only do operations on the generated arrays. maybe the trick is indeed using the indices. But I fail doing so

Comment: I've voted to reopen: As noted by others, the question isn't fully specified since it's unclear whether to sort or just plot the points.  But there are only a couple of reasonable ways to approach the answer, and imho, "two possible answers" != "too many possible answers".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use matplotlib.pyplot you can plot them as a scatter plot and get a rough approximation of a sine wave.

For example using your x and y arrays:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.random.rand(1000)*2
Y = np.sin(X)
plt.scatter(X,Y)
plt.show()
```

You'll end up with something like this:

[image]

**EDIT**
Per your comment I ran this for you:

```
sortx = np.argsort(X)
plt.plot(X[sortx], Y[sortx], marker='.')
plt.show()
```

You'll get this approximation:
[image]

You have to pass the argsort indices into X so that it plots them in the correct order and do the same for Y that way you get a nice smooth line (at least for where your data is most dense).

If you want a smooth line representation of the sine wave then you could just say:

```
z = np.arange(-6.28, 6.28, 0.1)
plt.plot(z, np.sin(z))
plt.show()
```

You'll end up with this:
[image]

Obviously, you may want to adjust the x axis ticks to represent values of pi for a better representation, but i think you get the idea.

Comment: oh thank you so much! this helped me a lot. but just another question. is there an option to use argsort? I mean I know what argsort does. It gives us an array of the indices of the values back. When I told it o my tutor that I used argsort, he said it's the right direction. but my code failed (see writing further up) As I told, we can only do operations on the generated arrays and we mustn't change the way arrays the are generated.

Comment: you could make a scatterplot using the argsort(X) but it would be the same as my first graph. I'm not sure what your assignment is but I don't really see a difference from using np.argsort() or np.sort(). Is it that you have to use Y as you originally have it posted `Y=np.sin(X)`?

Comment: yes, exactely. We have these two constraints: you can only do operations on the generated arrays and do not change the way arrays are generated. that's why I am just confused and I am not sure how much I can change these arrays. And as my tutor said argsort is the right direction, I thought it's the trick...first I thought I have to sort the array. But now I wonder, whether we should use the indices...

Comment: I got ya. So what you would need to do is feed in the indicesx as the index paramater for X and Y. Like so `plt.plot(X[indicesx], Y[indicesx])` That will plot them in order of the argsort index thus giving you the proper line.

Comment: oh man. Totally what I was looking for! Thank you so much! The failure I had was, I used the wrong Y values...

Comment: @K_Lomex if that answers the question could you mark as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can just plot the data you are generating using `matplotlib`. Like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X = np.random.randn(1000)*2
Y = np.sin(X)
plt.plot(X,Y,'green',linestyle='none',marker='.')
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want the points to be connected by a line, then remove `linestyle='none'`. But in order to avoid chaotic plotting, also sort your random numbers first, then define Y.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X = np.random.randn(1000)*2
X=sorted(X)
Y = np.sin(X)
plt.plot(X,Y,'red',marker='.')
plt.show()
```

[image]